# Why are these functions linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

$f1(x) = x$

$f2(x) = x^2$

$f3(x) = 5x - 4x^2$

From my understanding a set of functions are only linearly dependent if you can show that one function is simply a scaled version of another in the same set, but I don't see how that is possible here. Can someone please show me what I'm missing?

Comment: $5 f_1 - 4_2 = f_3$, that is we can write $f_3$ as a linear combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$. A linear combination being an expression constructed from a set of terms by multiplying each term by a constant and adding the results.

Comment: Not "a scaled version", but "a sum of scaled versions". Yours is an example, but there are others that require the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement "a set of functions are only linearly dependent if you can show that one function is simply a scaled version of another in the same set" is not quite right.

A set of functions $\{f_1, \dotsc, f_n\}$ is linearly dependent if you can write one as a **linear combination** of the others, i.e. if there are numbers $a_2, \dotsc, a_n$ such that
$$ f_1 = a_2 f_2 + \dotsb + a_n f_n.$$

In your example,
$$f_3 = 5f_1 - 4f_2.$$